# How can i detect what link is the mouse cursor is currently hovering on when the user is surfing with his Web Browser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseover

In the Windows.Forms application, i want to add an option to auto detect some specific links when the user is surfing the web using his web browser ( safari, chrome, firefox etc...), i want to make my program check for the current link that the mouse is hovering on each interval of time using a timer, then if a specific link is detected, it simply displays a simple MessageBox which let me know that i hovered on that link.

For exemple, i enter to stackoverflow, then a set my application to check for the following link

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/faq
```

Then when i run my application, and enter to stackoverflow and move the mouse cursor over tha faq link in the top right of site, a Message box will be shown letting me know that i am hovering on that link

[image]

Is this possible ? And how can i detect what link is the mouse cursor is currently hovering on when the user is surfing with his Web Browser ?

Thankyou in advance !

Comment: You want to make a spy program?

Comment: @SteveWellens I don't think so. Its his Win forms application that user's will browse. It can also be checking for unwanted links.

Comment: @Shoban - That doesn't seem to be the case "surfing the web using his web browser ( safari, chrome, firefox etc...)"

Comment: Oops! Sorry! :-) I did not read the question properly.

Comment: nope, what i'm trying to do is to create a program that run in background and inform my employees whenever they hover on some restricted domains used on the websites related to our company that are using some forbidden domains.. So they remove them..

Comment: Who removes them?  Would it not be easier just to restrict the domains and show the user a message after they've clicked an unsupported link?

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do this is to hook into the running process.

See [Gray Hat Python - pg. 86](http://books.google.com/books?id=EVuk7eqhWiwC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=hooking%20the%20browser%20process&source=bl&ots=iclyhGZGMB&sig=JA4KaMvOKYYY65XhgKybz1_baFo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-CCMT7xrhtnRAcPztegJ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=hooking%20the%20browser%20process&f=false) at Google books to get you started.

Comment: I'd add your comment about restricting the domains into this answer too, as that seems like a much more sensible way of going about it!